# How to Call third party API in flask restful web app

Tags: api, flask, python-requests, integration, flask-restful

I'm trying to call GET API of third party in my current flask web app,
I want to understand how to call get from current web app and display the data fetched / received in JSON format on to the web page

- How to Call GET from own web app
- Where to receive the response in JSON format
- How to display the received response on web page

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: I want to create a web app in flask (python) ,which would call get api of another website ,which in result will respond / return as json page with lots of info ...this info I wish to display in my web page ..how to do that ?